# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined

Tags: extjs

If I change model primaryKey remove run code is not error,but other event don't execute.such as itemclick, itemcontentmenu.

My sencha extjs version is 6.0.who can help me.

view code:

```
{
    xtype : 'dataview',
    autoScroll:true,
    bind: '{houseStoreLocal}',
    tpl: [
        '<div id="separate">',
        '<div id="rentalContainer">',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '   <div class="xsd-font-size16 top xsd-margin-t16">',
        '       <a class="apartment" data-target="#houseDetail">{dy}</a>',//{lc}
        '   </div>',
        '   <ul class="roomList xsd-clearfix">',
        '   <tpl for="children">',
        '       <li>',
        '           <dl>',
        '               <dt><a style="color:#6b6b6b;{lcStyle}">{lc}{no}室</a></dt>',
        '               <dd><i class="{stateStyle}"></i>',
        '                   <a style="color:#000;">{cqr}</a><img>',
        '                   <div class="contract_card">',
        '                       <div class="card_top card_top_bule">',
        '                           <p>点击查看房屋详情</p>',
        '                       </div>',
        '                   </div>',
        '               </dd>',
        '           </dl>',
        '       </li>',
        '   </tpl>',
        '   </ul>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ],
    selectionModel: {mode   : 'MULTI'},
    trackOver: true,
    itemSelector: 'li',
    emptyText: '<div style="width:100%;font-size: 18px;text-align:center;">暂无房屋信息</div>',
    prepareData: function(data,recordIndex,record) {
        Ext.apply(data, {
            cqr: data.cqr?Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(data.cqr, 15):'暂无产权人信息',
            stateStyle : data.cqr?'xsd-bg-primary':'xsd-bg-gray',
            lcStyle : ''
        });
        return data;
    },
    listeners: {
        itemclick : 'houseSelected',
        itemcontextmenu : 'houseItemContextMenu',
        containercontextmenu : 'houseContainerContextMenu'
    }
}
```

store code:

```
houseStoreLocal : {
    xtype : 'tree',
    sorters:[{property:'cfxh',direction: 'ASC'}],
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : app.base + '/project/house/findByTree.do',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'list'
        }
    }
}
```

my questions is run this view,brower tip error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined
    at constructor.updateIndexes (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:165745)
    at constructor.refresh (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:165320)
    at constructor.callParent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:11714)
    at constructor.refresh (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:166960)
    at constructor.refreshView (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:165893)
    at constructor.onDataRefresh (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:165876)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:19779)
    at constructor.doFireEvent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:20685)
    at constructor.prototype.doFireEvent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:54106)
    at constructor.fireEventArgs (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20171126154334:20539)
```

Comment: Your template can't be like that. The itemSelector has to map 1-1 with each record.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I don't know what you mean. my program run is not waring,if i change my template li fields to <li class="demo"> .itemSelector change to 'li.demo' .program run no error , but get records has problem

Comment: It's not a 1-1 mapping. For each record in the store, you're looping over "children" and creating a DOM node to match the item selector. That's not how dataviews work.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli  my resultset has parent and children ,so i use double looping,first floor looping is parent array , second floor looping is children ,my opertion is second floor,first floor just show not hava any opertion. you say 1-1 mapping what's meaning???

Comment: @EvanTrimboli What I need to do if I want to add one more element in dataview which is not present in store, Any workaround for that.